# Swift - Accessing Address Book to get array of numbers

Tags: ios, swift

I've been trying to do this for a while i.e. access the contacts on the phone and get all the mobile numbers on an array, but so far didn't reach far. I came across a library today that kind of cleanses the process yet I am stuck getting the numbers only into an array.

The following is the code:

```
SwiftAddressBook.requestAccessWithCompletion({ (success, error) -> Void in
            if success {
                if let people = swiftAddressBook?.allPeople {
                    for person in people {
                        NSLog("%@", (person.phoneNumbers?.map( {$0.value} ))!)
                    }
                }
            }
            else {
                //no success. Optionally evaluate error
                print("Access Red")
            }
        })
```

when that NSLog prints, I get the following in console:

```
2016-01-25 19:24:20.392 app[39001:7408159] (
    "(555) 564-8583",
    "(415) 555-3695"
)
2016-01-25 19:24:20.393 app[39001:7408159] (
    "555-478-7672",
    "(408) 555-5270",
    "(408) 555-3514"
)
2016-01-25 19:24:20.393 app[39001:7408159] (
    "888-555-5512",
    "888-555-1212"
)
2016-01-25 19:24:20.393 app[39001:7408159] (
    "555-522-8243"
)
2016-01-25 19:24:20.393 app[39001:7408159] (
    "(555) 766-4823",
    "(707) 555-1854"
)
2016-01-25 19:24:20.394 app[39001:7408159] (
    "555-610-6679"
)
```

How can I get the numbers only of those contacts into an array of String type? The purpose here is to actually query against that array in the backend and get all members by their phone numbers.

The link to the library is here in case further reference is needed:

[Link To Library](https://github.com/SocialbitGmbH/SwiftAddressBook)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Essentially what you are printing is a lot of smaller arrays resembling a group of phone numbers for the same person. I would merge all those smaller arrays into one.

How about this:

```
SwiftAddressBook.requestAccessWithCompletion({ (success, error) -> Void in
        if success {
            if let people = swiftAddressBook?.allPeople {
                let arrayOfArrays = people.flatMap({$0.phoneNumbers?.map( {$0.value})})
                print(arrayOfArrays.flatMap({ $0 }))
            }
        }
        else {
            //no success. Optionally evaluate error
            print("Access Red")
        }
    })
```

Comment: yes but I wanted to have an array such as: ["number","number",...]

Comment: basically I don't care what numbers came together or not since I will be running all numbers against the database anyway

Comment: Well that code is exactly what you want, did you test it?

Comment: yes and I got this: [["(555) 564-8583", "(415) 555-3695"], ["555-478-7672", "(408) 555-5270", "(408) 555-3514"], ["888-555-5512", "888-555-1212"], ["555-522-8243"], ["(555) 766-4823", "(707) 555-1854"], ["555-610-6679"]].

As you can see, some elements are arrays in their own and they contain 2 items for example. I want one array with each element being a single phone number, not an array

Comment: ahh, i forgot to add the other flatMap, try now.

Comment: excellent that's exactly what I expected to have. Thanks a lot Yarneo.

Comment: sorry to bother, but I am trying to copy the array of arrays to a regular array of [String] type but its not allowing. Apparently it shows that arrayOfArrays is [[String]] and that's not compatible with [String]. Any way around that?

Comment: You need to use the printed value, which is this:
let finalArray = arrayOfArrays.flatMap({ $0 }